# Multiple query and separate then for binding?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

Is it possible to do multiple query's in the same .php and bind them to show in different places?

For example I'm using:

```html
<?php
include 'dbc.php';
$query = "SELECT art_price, art_header, art_pic, art_row1, art_row2, art_row3, art_row4 FROM signs WHERE art_number = ?";

if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['art_number']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rowPrice, $rowHeader, $rowPic, $rowArt1, $rowArt2, $rowArt3, $rowArt4);


    while($stmt->fetch()){
        
        ?>
```

And then displaying the result with

```
<?=$rowPic?>
```

But I wanna be able to use another "$_POST['art_number2']" to get bound to

```
<?=$rowPic2?>
```

Is this possible? and how?
Thankful for answers!

Changed this to:

```html
<?php
include 'dbc.php';
$query = "SELECT art_price, art_header, art_pic, art_row1, art_row2, art_row3, art_row4 FROM signs WHERE art_number = ?";

if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['art_number']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rowPrice, $rowHeader, $rowPic, $rowArt1, $rowArt2, $rowArt3, $rowArt4);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['art_number2']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rowPrice2, $rowHeader2, $rowPic2, $rowArt12, $rowArt22, $rowArt32, $rowArt42);


    while($stmt->fetch()){
        
        ?>
```

Now only the second selection shows as result.

Comment: Call `bind_param` and `execute` again.

Comment: How do I do that?
Sorry but I've never worked with php and mysql before.

Comment: [The documentation covers this.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Edit your question when adding large chunks of code like that. A comment makes it very hard to read.

Comment: I've gone trough all of the documentation twice, also tried a lot of things suggested at other sites, not getting it to work.. :(
Please if anyone knows how to solve this, show me so I can understand this!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'dbc.php';
$query = "SELECT art_price, art_header, art_pic, art_row1, art_row2, art_row3, art_row4 FROM signs WHERE art_number = ?";

if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['art_number']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rowPrice, $rowHeader, $rowPic, $rowArt1, $rowArt2, $rowArt3, $rowArt4);

    while($stmt->fetch()){

        ?> ... <?php
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['art_number2']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rowPrice2, $rowHeader2, $rowPic2, $rowArt12, $rowArt22, $rowArt32, $rowArt42);


    while($stmt->fetch()){

        ?>
```